# style.backgroundColor not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to change the background color of an element on a click event..
But the code seems not to be working..

Html

```
<td  class="white" onclick="place(this,1,2)"></td>
```

Style

```
<style>
        .black{
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            background-color:black;
        }
        .white{
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            background-color:white;

        }
    </style>
```

Below is a javascript function used..

```
function place(domObj,row,col){

            alert(domObj.style.backgroundColor);


        }
```

alert returns null..

Comment: What you are doing here?

Comment: If you want to **get** the current background color, use `window.getComputedStyle()`. The `style` object will not include properties set by global or external styles sheets.

Comment: so do you want to toggle back-ground color from white to black and vice-versa on button click ?

Comment: @Pawal Yea.. i want to toggle the background color.. but have no idea of how to do that..

Comment: why are you not using addClass and removeClass to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `domObj.style` only returns styles that are set inline using the `style` attribute.

For styles that come from a CSS file you need to use something like: `window.getComputedStyle`

Example from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container"); // this is your domObj
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
```

Description:

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS
>   properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and
>   resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

For your case your function should look like this:

```
function place(domObj,row,col){

    alert(window.getComputedStyle(domObj,null).getPropertyValue("background-color"));

}
```

#### Update

Since Internet Explorer 7, colors are always returned in RGB values. There is not way to return it directly, but you can convert it from RGB to hex with this snippet:

```
    bg = bg.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]) + hex(bg[3]);
```

where `bg` is the RGB background string.

Comment: I am getting the output in rgb(0,0,0)..is there anyway that we could get it as a string just like the one we set..?

Comment: @surendhar_s no easy way, you may have to use some kind of mapper between `rgb` and the possible color keyword, also you can try using `cssRule` to get the property, not sure about that ***however*** cssRule will help you get the property in just that rule, other rules may override it, hence `getComputedStyle` is still a different thing.

Comment: he does not mean the hex string of color, he means the color keyword like `black`, `white`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the className property of element.

your javascript code will be something like this

```
function place(ctrl)
{
    ctrl.className =(ctrl.className=="white"?"black":"white");
}
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ALvn6/)